# Search for special character U+FFFD (65533) with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, special-characters

Im going to search for every occurrence of a character in a .txt file. It is "�" or better known as 0xFFFD.
Well, i get everything to work if i am searching for a normal string, but i don't get to work this special character.
Imagine i have a specific line in a text file referred by $line and the special character im talking about is in it, for example:

```
$line = 'you cann cho�se f�r everyone'
```

Then I have tried to create the following variables:

```
$SearchCharacter1 = "�"
$SearchCharacter2 = $([char]0xFFFD)
```

Then i have used both of them in the following Powershell code using the Select-String command

```
        if($line | Select-String -Pattern $SearchCharacter -SimpleMatch)
        {
            Write-Host "Character involved"
        }else
        {
            Write-Host "Character not involved"
        }
```

I have also tried a simple contains statement like this:

```
        if($line.Contains($SearchCharacter))
        {
            Write-Host "Character involved"
        }else
        {
            Write-Host "Character not involved"
        }
```

Does anyone what todo to get the Code working? What is so special about 0xFFFD? Why does everything work when i use a normal character.
Thanks for your time!

EDIT:
I get the line like this:

```
    foreach ($file in $files){
    $lines = Get-Content $file
    foreach ($line in $lines){
        # Check if the line contains the character we need to change.
        if($line -match $SearchCharacter)
        {
            # And now do sth with $line
```

Comment: Where the `$line` comes from? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: May need to use a different form of regex than piping to select-string.  I get a match with the below.    https://tio.run/##Zc1BCsIwFATQfU4xlEB1IegBulJygS6Li2@I/kBsS/4XeznxSB4hRsGVMJuB4c083UMWDimVYvtA2fOeKZPXkHfo0L6ej9ZY0RzHS4dGOQpqCKfb6BnTGRoWRZ1BmRRMApmDj5Tgf5LAroZPO24X59xh3RhjbP9FsbmSVunv3ZhS3g

Comment: `[char]0xFFFD` Is Unicode _REPLACEMENT CHARACTER_ (CodePoint U+FFFD) and I doubt that it's really present in an _ordinary_ text file - regardless you can see it in output from `Get-Content $file` on the screen…

Comment: @JosefZ, i did. It cames from a "line-array" returned by the Get-Content command.

Comment: This is missing quotes:  `$line = you cann cho�se f�r everyone`.  What encoding is the file?  It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is the file is encoded as utf8nobom, and you're using powershell 5, which won't recognize the encoding automatically.  For that you have to specify the encoding:

```
get-content file -encoding utf8 | select-string �

you cann cho�se f�r everyone
```

UTF8 encodes � as "EF BF BD":

```
format-hex file


   Label: /Users/js/file

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 79 6F 75 20 63 61 6E 6E 20 63 68 6F EF BF BD 73 you cann choï¿½s
0000000000000010 65 20 66 EF BF BD 72 20 65 76 65 72 79 6F 6E 65 e fï¿½r everyone
0000000000000020 0A                                              �
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
   if($line -match $SearchCharacter) {
     Write-Host "Character involved"
   }
   else {
     Write-Host "Character not involved"
   }
```

Comment: Hmm Your example works for me. So it seems like my "line object" $line is the problem. Im pretty new to PS. I get the line from a text file. I edited my post to show how i did this.

Comment: In your example $line you do not have the phrase in quotes.  In that example it will error and your variable would be null. Put it in quotes and it would be a string and should produce a match. With the variable you get  from your textfile Pipe the variable to gm ($line | gm) And make sure it's a string.

Comment: Of course I forgot the quotes. But this was not the problem. Your solution was also right, thanks a lot! But it seems to be much slower than the solution of "js2010".